# Having trouble comparing dates Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm new to Access and i'm having trouble with comparing dates in my SQL Query. I can't seem to work around this problem. It works fine if it just input a date like this:

```
Dim SendTo as string, strSQL as string

DateF = Me.txtDate.value

strSQL = "UPDATE [" & Team & "] SET [" & Init & "] = '" & SendTo & "' WHERE Date = #2020-01-06#;"
```

I want the date to be a variable set by a textbox on a userform, like this:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [" & Team & "] SET [" & Init & "] = '" & SendTo & "' WHERE Date = DateF"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

When i do this, a pop-up box show "Enter parameter value"

Comment: The error is because DateF is inside the quotes and therefore part of the SQL statement, but has no meaning in that context. You probable need something like `"' WHERE Date =" & DateF` or `"' WHERE Date = #" & DateF & "#"` but I don't know the exact details.

Comment: @SilverRampart Thank you so much! - it did work. I needed to format the date, for it to work though.